# How can I add data in nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, math, nunjucks

I want to show the answer for adding two data values that a user has entered in the front end, in nunjucks.

I've tried:

`{{data['firstanswer'] + data['secondanswer']}}`

And

`{% set total = (data['firstanswer'] + data['secondanswer'] %} {{total}}`

I keep getting 22 for a sum like 2+2, but * and / works fine.

I've followed https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#math

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#float

Comment: Ok got it, thanks {{data['firstanswer'] | float + data['secondanswer'] | float }}